# Different validations for two different submit buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

We have a screen with two different submit buttons: Upload and Submit. Each button is on a separate form. The Upload button is to submit and validate an uploaded Excel file. The Submit button is used submit and validate that some dropdown box selections have been made. Essentially, each button should have different validation conditions.

Right now I'm using ModelState.IsValid to validate the uploaded Excel file. However, when I Submit the form IsValid tries to validate the file again. The problem is that the file no longer exists in ModelState. How could I set up different validation conditions for each of these buttons? That way file validation is not performed on the Submit button, only the Upload button. Would I use two different models?

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing everything with one submit action? Or to not have 2 separate forms?

Comment: Yes, the second form will show data pulled from the validated Excel file. The user will then manipulate that data and Submit. The second Submit action only needs to validate those manipulations.

Comment: So if you do have 2 separate forms, why not use separate models that post back to separate methods

Comment: Yes I think that may be the way to go. The forms are both on the same .cshtml page which is strongly typed to the view model. Can I strongly type the view to a second view model? Or do I need a separate .cshtml page?

Comment: Create a view model that contains 2 properties, one for each of the model in the forms, but you will need to use the `[Bind(Prefix="..")]` attribute when you post back, or use partials so the controls are not prefixed with the property name.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Do you have any more information on how this is done?

Comment: you can use ajax to submit that excel data, postback and update the form with the new values and use the main submit for the actionresult [HttpPost] ... maybe

Comment: @gerdi: That was my original idea. I started writing it (and go pretty far along) then realized it was getting pretty complex. We like to keep things simple even if that means resubmitting the form a few times.